# Why is there an empty line after every record when writing a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have some lists and want to write them in a CSV file.
Every list has 9200 items.

And every list must be a column in a CSV file.

I write this code:

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(folder_name), 'file_wanted.csv')
file_list = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5, list_6, list_7, list_8]
exported = zip_longest(*file_list)

with open(file_path, "w+", errors="ignore") as file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerow(["list_1", "list_2", "list_3", "list_4", "list_5", "list_6", "list_7", "list_8"])
    write.writerows(exported)
```

But I have the file like that

[image: Csv file I have]

Is there a better way to write the code so that the extra line doesn't bloom for me after every record

Comment: Is the image in your question the input or output?

Comment: Why do the column names in the image not match the column names in the code? Does `places_name` = `list_1`, `country` = `list_2`, etc...? Something like that?

Comment: Also, please don't use an image of the output. We cannot see quote chars, and it's harder to interpret what's going on. Please copy-paste _some_ lines from the actual output.

Comment: This image for the output file and the column doesn't match because I won't write it to the general case

Answer (score 0):

If there is an empty line every second line, you need to add `newline=''` like so:

```
with open(file_path,"w+",errors="ignore", newline='') as file:
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas is your friend.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, os
from itertools import zip_longest

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(folder_name))
exported = list(zip_longest(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, 
                            list_5, list_6, list_7, list_8, fillvalue=np.nan))

df = pd.DataFrame(exported)
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
```